# How can I display the contents of every table row directly in the tr tag in an Angular 8 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been working an app with Angular 8.

The **employee-list** component displays data in a table.

In `employee-list.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../../models/empModel';
import * as data from '../../data/employees';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css'],
})
export class EmployeeListComponent {
  public displayMode: String = 'grid';
  public deptno: number = -1;
  public empsArray: Employee[] = data.employees;

  public removeEmployee(empno: number) {
    this.empsArray = this.empsArray.filter((item) => item.empno != empno);
  }

  public filterByDepartment(num: number) {
    this.deptno = num;
  }

  public setDisplayMode(mode: String) {
    this.displayMode = mode;
  }
}
```

In the view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Full Name</th>
          <th>Job</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of empsArray | filter: deptno">
          <app-employee-table-item
            [employee]="employee"
          ></app-employee-table-item>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

As can be seen above, the contents of each table row is handled by a (child)component, called **employee-table-item**:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../../models/empModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-table-item',
  templateUrl: './employee-table-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-table-item.component.css'],
})
export class EmployeeTableItemComponent {
  @Input() employee: Employee;
}
```

#### The problem

The table is diplsyed wrongly, due to the fact that the contents of every table row is wrapped in a `<app-employee-table-item></app-employee-table-item>` element.

I want display the contents of every table row *directly* in the  tag, while keeping the template in a *distinct HTML* file.

#### Question

What is the most reliable way to display the contents of every table row *directly* in the `<tr>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to use your component as a directive. It is pretty common to do that exactly in your case.

app-employee-table-item:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[appEmployeeTableItem],app-employee-table-item',
  templateUrl: './employee-table-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-table-item.component.css'],
})
export class EmployeeTableItemComponent {
  @Input('appEmployeeTableItem') employee: Employee;
}
```

EmployeeList.html :

```
  <tbody>
    <tr
      *ngFor="let employee of empsArray | filter: deptno"
      [appEmployeeTableItem]="employee"
    ></tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Great, but now, if I want to attach an event to the table row, `(OnEmployeeRemove)="removeEmployee($event)`, it does not work.

Comment: it should work without any problem. Explain your problem please/ show your code.

Comment: @Input('appEmployeeTableItem') employee: Employee;
  @Output('appEmployeeTableItem') OnEmployeeRemove: EventEmitter<number> =
    new EventEmitter();   please read your code more than 2min before posting a question... the output name is wrong

Comment: it should be Output() OnEmployeeRemove or Output('whatYouWantInYourHtml') OnEmployeeRemove;

Answer (score 1):

An approach you can use is to fix this is to change from using a **tag selector** to using an **attribute value selector**.

In **employee-list.component.html**, replace

```
<tr *ngFor="let employee of empsArray | filter: deptno">
    <app-employee-table-item
        [employee]="employee"
    ></app-employee-table-item>
</tr>
```

with this:

```
<tr
    data-selector="app-employee-table-item"
    *ngFor="let employee of empsArray | filter: deptno"
    [employee]="employee"
></tr>
```

In **employee-table-item.component.ts**, change the selector to

```
selector: '[data-selector=app-employee-table-item]',
```

Now, instead of looking for `<app-employee-table-item\>` HTML elements,  Angular will look for any HTML elements with an attribute called `data-selector` with value of `app-employee-table-item` and replace that element with your template.

Your Stackblitz, forked, with this change: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstrap-ke3bbc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Femployee-list%2Femployee-list.component.html